What does IpOutDiscard in RFC1213 / nstat actually mean?
I am trying to understand what are "discarded packets", in ipOutDiscards , as defined in RFC1213

"The number of output IP datagrams for which no
problem was encountered to prevent their
transmission to their destination, but which were
discarded (e.g., for lack of buffer space).  Note
that this counter would include datagrams counted
in ipForwDatagrams if any such packets met this
(discretionary) discard criterion."

I don't understand what side is discarding the packets.
If I have a high ipOutDiscards, does it mean my side is discarding the packets, or the other side? In other words, is the IP packet transferred or not?

If this questions is more in server fault, or Linux SE, please mark is as such. I was not sure where to put it.

ipOutDiscards are discarded before egress/being transmitted, e.g., for lack of buffer space, ie. when the port queue is full and the current packet can't be queued. If QoS is in place, a higher priority might be hogging the link, or there's simply too much ingress traffic for that egress port.

does it mean my side is discarding the packets, or the other side?

The side where the ipOutDiscards are counted.

In other words, is the IP packet transferred or not?

It's not.

If you think about how it works, this is the only possible answer. It can't be discarded after it is sent. It has to be discarded at the interface on the device that was attempting to transmit it but was unable to do so for whatever reason.
